# The probability of selecting four parties

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In mathematicians land facing four different parties: a, b, c, d.
>   6 people do not know who to vote for, so choose at random any political party. 
>   What is the probability Party A will receive 2 votes, Party B will receive 2 votes
>   And Party C will get two votes?

**I tried to think of it this way:**

$$\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{6}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{1}{1}\binom{2}{2}}{4^6}$$
I mean, I choose a party from the three parties, and I choose her 2 voters

The answer by the book is:
$$\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}}{4^6}$$

Why they chose only the voters? And did not choose the party get their votes?
I do not know what I'm missing to get answer similar to their own.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing $6 \choose 2$, you are choosing $2$ people to vote for party $A$ and then by doing $4 \choose 2$, you are choosing $2$ people to vote for party $B$ and then by doing $2 \choose 2$ you are choosing $2$ people to vote for party $C$.

By adding in the ${3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}{1 \choose 1}$, you are accounting for the different ways you can do this (e.g. choosing people for $B$, then $A$, then $C$ or choosing people for $C$, then $A$, then $B$).

However, this is redundant because it does not matter what order you choose the people who are going to vote for which party because you can get the same possibilities by picking certain people for certain parties regardless of what order you pick them in.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope that in the end I catch all the tricks